# Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlBoolean to a Boolean

Tags: c#

I am trying to save data in an Access database file.

[image]

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   myapp.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a
>   SqlBoolean to a Boolean.
>
> Inner Exception: "Object must implement IConvertible.

I am unable to find the exact point of code which is liable for this exception.

**Where should I find the cause?**

**DBNullValue.cs**

```
public class DBNullValue
{
    public static Object GetNullValue(DbType dataType)
    {
        Object returnValue;

        switch (dataType)
        {
            case DbType.AnsiString:
            case DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:
            case DbType.String:
            case DbType.StringFixedLength:
                returnValue = SqlString.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Double:
                returnValue = SqlDouble.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Decimal:
            case DbType.VarNumeric:
                returnValue = SqlDecimal.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Single:
                returnValue = SqlSingle.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Int16:
                returnValue = SqlInt16.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Int32:
                returnValue = SqlInt32.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Int64:
                returnValue = SqlInt64.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.UInt16:
                returnValue = SqlInt32.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.UInt32:
                returnValue = SqlInt64.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.UInt64:
                returnValue = SqlInt64.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Byte:
            case DbType.SByte:
                returnValue = SqlByte.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Boolean:
                returnValue = SqlBoolean.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.DateTime:
            case DbType.Date:
            case DbType.DateTime2:
            case DbType.DateTimeOffset:
            case DbType.Time:
                returnValue = SqlDateTime.Null;
                break;

            case DbType.Binary:
            case DbType.Object:
            default:
                returnValue = DBNull.Value;
                break;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that there are debuggers that you can use to figure out the exact line of code where your exception is thrown? And that the exception has a stack trace that tells you the line right away?

Comment: @Sefe, its something with `DBNull`. Stack trace doesn't give anything significant.

Comment: You should just be able to use `DBNull.Value` instead of doing `GetNullValue` which returns `object` and therefore not an IConvertible. `DBNull` does implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: @Crowcoder, thanks. that solved my problem.